# slash with number after color declaration in CSS

Tags: css

I have found this in several locations in the CSS of a Wordpress theme:

```
.green {background-color: #080808 \9;}
```

What is the \9 used for?

Answer (score 2):

\9 is a "CSS hack" specific to Internet Explorer 7, 8, & 9.

This simply means that the one specific line of CSS ending with a `\9;` in place of the `;` is only valid in IE 7, 8, & 9.

In your example,

`background-color: #080808 \9;` means that a `background-color` `#080808`  will only be applied while using IE 7, 8, & 9.

For more information visit  [webdesignandsuch.com/ie9-specific-css-hack/](http://webdesignandsuch.com/ie9-specific-css-hack/)